# Создание нового объекта сущности ADO Model

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, entity-framework, ado.net

У меня есть база данных SQL с  таблицами, я создаю Модель ADO.NET EDM, получаю всю базу данных в виде сущностей. При создании новых объектов и записи в базу не получается создать несколько. И так, проблему я получаю с:

```
public partial class Contracts
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Contracts()
    {
        this.Sales = new ObservableCollection<Sales>();
    }

    public int ContractID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateOfIssue { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateOfExecution { get; set; }

    public virtual Customers Customers { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Sales> Sales { get; set; }
}
```

Я пытаюсь создать новый Contracts так:

```
Contracts newContr = new Contracts
                {
                    ContractID = mod.ContractID,
                    DateOfExecution = mod.DateOfExecution,
                    DateOfIssue = mod.DateOfIssue,
                    Customers = new Customers()
                };
myBase.SaveChanges();
```

Customers:

```
public partial class Customers
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Customers()
    {
        this.Contracts = new ObservableCollection<Contracts>();
    }

    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string TelNumber { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Contracts> Contracts { get; set; }
}
```

Но получаю следующую ошибку:

> UpdateException: Entities in 'MyBaseEntities.Contracts' participate in the 'FK_Contracts_Customers' relationship. 0 related 'Customers' were found. 1 'Customers' is expected.

[image: Добавление нового Contracts]
[image: Exception]
[image: Таблица Customers]
[image: Таблица Contracts]

Comment: ну а что вот это должно значить с точки зрения базы данных? `Customers = new Customers()`

Comment: @tym32167, простите меня но я не понимаю. Но мне кажется что должна быть связь. А я её не правильно реализую. Вопрос в том, что когда я просто подключаюсь к базе через sql запросы, всё отлично работает.

Comment: Дословно ваш код означает `База, обнови в таблице Контрактов вот такую запись и ассоциируй её с Клиентом, которого я только что придумал и которого в базе нет`, на что база вам отвечает `Я не могу обновить ассоциацию с Клиентом, которого нет в таблице Клиентов`

Comment: @tym32167, Окей даже когда я пытаюсь с существующим не даёт создать.

Comment: `даже когда я пытаюсь с существующим` то есть вы что то сделали, у вас что то не получилось, вы это не показываете, но спрашиваете как пофиксить?

Comment: @tym32167, даже когда я делаю так для `Customer=new Customers { CustomerID=5, Address="Politiki", Name="Igor", TelNumber="32302"}` я получаю эту же ошибку

Comment: Здесь уже проблема с контекстом данных. Чтобы использовать Customer, вам надо его сначала получить из базы. Вы не можете просто взять и создать Customer и использовать его во внешних связях. Это если я верно помню, т.к. не работал с базами давненько.

Comment: @tym32167, чёрт, как по нормальному это сделать то. Сначала получить список Customer из базы? потом создать нового сохранить, и ещё раз сохранить при создании Contracts?? Но если я выбираю из существующего Customers, тоже могу получить эту ошибку я пробовал так : `Customers = (from m in myBase.Customers.Local where m.CustomerID == 2 select m).FirstOrDefault()` и тоже самое

Comment: Сделайте наоборот: `cust.Contracts.Add(newContr)`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не сработало

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё такая возможность, но не знаю, сработает ли она у вас, но давайте попробуем. Код я пишу по памяти, потому мелкие ошибки поправите сами.

1) Создаем и привязываем Клиента (при этом мы берем ID существующего клиента в бд)

```
var сustomers = new Customers(){CustomerID = 2};
```

2) Привязывем его к контексту

```
myBase.Attach(сustomers);
```

3) Создаем `Contracts`

```
var newContr = new Contracts
{
    // ИД вы руками что ли запоняете? Это должен быть автоинкремент в БД
    // ContractID = mod.ContractID, 
    DateOfExecution = mod.DateOfExecution,
    DateOfIssue = mod.DateOfIssue,
    Customers = сustomers
};
```

4) Добавляем его в контекст

```
 myBase.Contracts.Add(newContr);
```

5) Сохраняем

```
myBase.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Что за метод Attach? У меня его нет.

Comment: @Valera у вас какая версия EF? Если нет то попробуйте всё таки `var сustomers =myBase.Customers.Where(c=>c.CustomerID == 2).Single()`;

Comment: при создании ADO Model выбрал 6 версию, оно вытянуло все таблицы и не в одной сущности такого метода нету(

Comment: @Valera `Attach` -  метод контекста, а не сущности.

Comment: окей, в EF6 это может выглядеть как `myBase.Customers.Attach(сustomers);` ([дока](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state))

Comment: всё тоже самое. Что за беда такая то. Почему когда просто через sql запросы связывался с этой же бд не было таких проблем...

Comment: @Valera у вас вот это не работает? `var сustomers =myBase.Customers.Where(c=>c.CustomerID == 2).Single();` ? Какая ошибка при этом?

Comment: всё та же ошибка, что писал. я сделал сейчас так: `var cust = new Customers() { CustomerID=2};` затем `myBase.Customers.Attach(cust);` и дальше `Contracts newCont=new Contracts{}` и в поле Customers указал на cust. но при `myBase.SaveChanges();` выбрасывает ошибку. Тоже самое получаю, если использую linq

Comment: @Valera у вас не может быть `UpdateException`, если вы делаете то же, что я вам показал в ответе. Вы точно вот это `// ContractID = mod.ContractID,` ублади из кода? Вот это вызываете? ` myBase.Contracts.Add(newContr);`

Comment: да абсолютно сделал так, как вы указывали. Сейчас прикреплю скрин-шоты

Comment: я добавил скрины, я не знаю, чем они помогут, но я уже в "истерике", т.к. сижу больше недели с этим заданием, и как-то стыдно

Comment: @Valera так, я создал БД с 2 теблицами и сгенерил по ним EF6 модель, она у меня добавила поле CustomerID в класс контрактов. Где это поле у вас? ( [раз](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OWVg.png), [два](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sux1S.png) ). Покажите схему вашей БД вместе с внешними ключами и попробуйте перегенерировать модель

Comment: [диаграмма в бд](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhmVH.png) [диаграмма EF6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUn9q.png)  . И да, при создании модели, у меня возник вопрос почему не создается данное поле, хоть я его и создал в БД. Когда в модель включаю, только одну таблицу, всё ок. Создавал я по этапам : [Create a simple data application with WPF and Entity Framework 6](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-simple-data-application-with-wpf-and-entity-framework-6?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @Valera вы когда генерировали, возможно пропустили вот [эту галку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Tk7.png), которая по умолчанию отмечена должна быть

Comment: блин, возможно. Попробую с нуля создать

Comment: @Valera но даже без этой галки, вот [такой код](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXbsy.png) отрабатывает без проблем

Comment: вы абсолютно правы..

Comment: я совершенно не понимаю в таком случае почему у меня нет 

Comment: @Valera попробуйте сгенерировать эти доп поля и просто прописать в нем нужный айдишник. Если не получится, то вам придется вашу БД сэкспорить в SQL и выложить, так как не знаю, что там у вас за схема, но повторить вашу проблему не могу